# Spring scheduler (quartz) how to pauseAll schedulers and reschedule them before resumeAll

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

The need is such clear that first I pauseAll schedulers and before resumeAll I want to reschedule jobs (I mean change the trigger expressions) and make them resume with THE NEW trigger expressions not the former ones.

Is it possible rescheduling a scheduler while it is paused? In other words is it ok by doing the following?

```
        scheduler.pauseAll(); // pause first
        scheduler.rescheduleJob(...); // reschedule while it is paused??
        scheduler.resumeAll(); // resume All with the new job-trigger expressions as above
```

(I cannot test exact scenario because of restrictions about the project structure by now, I need time for build test and adapt to the project)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out today that it is possible to reschedule jobs even while scheduler is in pause state. Thus, I made it done by the following peace of code as I mentioned above:

```
    scheduler.pauseAll(); // pause first
    scheduler.rescheduleJob(...); // reschedule while it is paused
    scheduler.resumeAll(); // resume All
```